# Stop NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData method

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nskeyedunarchiver

In my app users can open up a file and I use `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to unarchive the data. To do this a user taps the file then I push a new view controller which starts the unarchive.

However, the user could quickly swipe back if they realize they tapped the wrong file. But, the problem here is that `unarchiveObjectWithData:` has already started and started taking up memory. If the user swipes back it does not cancel this method, memory is still used until that method completes.

```
NSArray *items = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:myData];
```

Is there any way to stop or cancel this method?

Comment: No. No way to stop it.

Comment: Only thing I can think of would be to dispatch it to an NSOperationQueue, at which point the *operation* itself *might* be cancellable?  I have my doubts, but might be worth a shot.